# Deserialise JSON in VB

Tags: json, vb.net

I am having trouble deserializing this JSON in VB..  I can only get hold of the value in each array but can't get the key which are the fieldnames in my tables.  You will note that each object can vary in size which I can handle on deserializing..

can anyone help?

```
{
"MATRIX": [
    {
        "1": "FM",
        "2": "4",
        "3": "Floor type",
        "4": "Standing water",
        "5": "Property unsafe"
    },
    {
        "1": "FM",
        "2": "4",
        "3": "Ceiling",
        "4": "Mould spores",
        "5": "Room/property still safe"
    },
    {
        "1": "FL",
        "2": "Basement",
        "3": "1"
    },
    {
        "1": "FL",
        "2": "External",
        "3": "7"
    },
    {
        "1": "FL",
        "2": "First Floor",
        "3": "3"
    },
    {
        "1": "FL",
        "2": "Garden",
        "3": "6"
    },
    {
        "1": "FL",
        "2": "Ground Floor",
        "3": "2"
    },
    {
        "1": "FL",
        "2": "Second Floor",
        "3": "4"
    },
    {
        "1": "FL",
        "2": "test 2",
        "3": "9"
    },
    {
        "1": "FL",
        "2": "Third Floor",
        "3": "5"
    },
    {
        "1": "CA",
        "2": "Bath",
        "3": "Bathroom",
        "4": "Bath"
    },
    {
        "1": "CA",
        "2": "Electrical",
        "3": "Bathroom",
        "4": "Bathroom Socket"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance,

D:)

Hi again..  I have tried the code from the second suggestion but cannot get the key and value for each item at the same time.  I get the keys and then the values for each iteration of my string..

this is what I am doing.  Please can you point out my error..

```
       Dim json As String = "{""items"":[{""Name"":""John"",""Age"":""20"",""Gender"":""Male""},{""Name2"":""Tom"",""Age2"":""25"",""Gender2"":""Male""},{""Name3"":""Sally"",""Age3"":""30"",""Gender3"":""Female""}]}"

    Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim data = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(json)

    For i = 0 To 2
        For Each key As String In data("items")(i).Keys
            MsgBox(key)
        Next
        'For Each item As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In data("items")
        For Each val As String In data("items")(i).Values
            MsgBox(val)
        Next
    Next
```

Thank you again,

Derek.

Comment: please include the code you are using

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON in Visual basic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079177/deserializing-json-in-visual-basic)

Comment: Also, that is invalid or incomplete and as constructed you will have trouble with properties named "1", "2", "3"...

Comment: Sorry Plutonix, I deleted my code as I managed to get away with using this..  Dim j As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(FaultJSON)
                For Each item As Object In j Next..  But I now have multiple objects in here and I will try the second suggestion.  You're right with the numbers, I will replace them with fieldnames I need.  Thank you..

Comment: dont deserialize to Object, create a Type (Class)

Comment: Hi Plutonix, I am a bit out of my depth with this.. can you point to some code which I can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you can use the keys to get the corresponding values, using something like this:

```
For Each item In data("items")
    Console.WriteLine("***item***")
    For Each key In item.Keys
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", key, item(key))
    Next
Next
```

which produces the following output:

```
***item***
Name:John
Age:20
Gender:Male
***item***
Name2:Tom
Age2:25
Gender2:Male
***item***
Name3:Sally
Age3:30
Gender3:Female
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, that was exactly what I needed..  Thank you all that helped and suggested too..  Much appreciated..