# How to read specific data fromJSON array to VB.net string?

Tags: vb.net, json.net

really need help, i need to make somehow to read from JSON array to VB.net string, specific value , this is my eg of array http://playnet.pro/client-files/gtracker/server.php?game=cssource&ip=216.52.148.47&port=27015

I made stream reader

```
Dim address As String = "http://playnet.pro/client-files/gtracker/server.php?game=cssource&ip=216.52.148.47&port=27015"
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
    Dim array As String = reader.ReadToEnd
```

but how to find my values or filter it? Thank you

Comment: You need to convert the PHP array to JSON on server side

Comment: Basically, JSON will create an interface between VB.NET and PHP

Comment: Ok i changed now file  to json http://playnet.pro/client-files/gtracker/server.php?game=cssource&ip=216.52.148.47&port=27015  , but i dont know how to read json specific value in vb.net

Comment: Are you using [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)? did you try to deserialize the data via [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

For parsing JSON in VB.NET, you have option to use any one of the below libraries:

*) **Newtonsoft.Json library** You can use this from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080586/4360419

*) **JSON.NET library** You can use this from [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Tutorial: You can also find the tutorial of this from the same side

You can also generate your VB.NET classes by your JSON from the below link 
http://jsontodatacontract.azurewebsites.net/