# json to vb.net with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, vb.net

i have the following json data:

```
{
  "offset": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 20.22,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "79.78",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 79.78,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "20.22",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "XAG/USD"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 35.26,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "64.74",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 64.74,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "35.26",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "GBP/USD"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 36.29,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "63.71",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 63.71,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "36.29",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "GBP/CHF"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 38.4,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "61.60",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 61.6,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "38.40",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "USD/JPY"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 40.34,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "59.66",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 59.66,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "40.34",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "XAU/USD"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 41,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "59.00",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 59,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "41.00",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "USD/CHF"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 41.39,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "58.61",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 58.61,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "41.39",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "AUD/JPY"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 45.43,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "54.57",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 54.57,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "45.43",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "EUR/CHF"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 45.48,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "54.52",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 54.52,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "45.48",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "NZD/USD"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 48.84,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "51.16",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 51.16,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "48.84",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "USD/CAD"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 50.44,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "49.56",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 49.56,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "50.44",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "EUR/AUD"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 51.58,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "48.42",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 48.42,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "51.58",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "GBP/JPY"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 53.16,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "46.84",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 46.84,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "53.16",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "AUD/USD"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 58.45,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "41.55",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 41.55,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "58.45",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "EUR/USD"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 60.59,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "39.41",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 39.41,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "60.59",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "EUR/JPY"
    },
    {
      "SHORT_NUMBER": 66.49,
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER/_source": "33.51",
      "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER": 33.51,
      "SHORT_NUMBER/_source": "66.49",
      "POSITION_VALUE": "EUR/GBP"
    }
  ],
  "cookies": [
    "__cfduid=\"d88d750e617563e514754b203f192fe331458847548\";Path=\"/\";Domain=\"www.oanda.com\";Port=\"443\"",
    "opc_id=\"36BD28AA-F1F6-11E5-99B2-BCE119644B1F\";Path=\"/\";Domain=\"www.oanda.com\";Port=\"443\""
  ],
  "connectorVersionGuid": "19b6b0c0-e763-4e8c-8927-134cf4389576",
  "connectorGuid": "3dfecdc1-e0bc-497d-a1f6-21608c7d8ec7",
  "pageUrl": "https://www.oanda.com/forex-trading/analysis/open-position-ratios",
  "outputProperties": [
    {
      "name": "POSITION_VALUE",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "LONGPOSITION_NUMBER",
      "type": "DOUBLE"
    },
    {
      "name": "SHORT_NUMBER",
      "type": "DOUBLE"
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to be able to list the position value : long position number : short number in a textbox or grid dataview.

so far i have gotten this far :

```
Dim uri As Uri = New Uri("https://api.import.io/store/connector/3dfecdc1-e0bc-497d-a1f6-21608c7d8ec7/_query?input=webpage/url:https%3A%2F%2Fwww.oanda.com%2Fforex-trading%2Fanalysis%2Fopen-position-ratios&&_apikey=d4c36ddd8f8d4a629bdf06e47993809233ac34a0ee817f4af327f7e016e1cb0921ba78b0da4d9be881051cbf3cf672f1425214d8e687e33559e24fdd17bc5a606e8ce1eac3d6e064593e3fcc34d23344")

  Dim wc1 As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
  Dim result As String = wc1.DownloadString(uri)
  Dim o1 As JObject = JObject.Parse(result)
  Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o1.Children().ToList
```

any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: It would help of you described what you are trying to do and asked an actual question.

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079177/deserializing-json-in-visual-basic)?